# Calculate Fourier series of $x(\pi^2-x^2)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am new to fourier series and i don't really know if i have understood correctly the whole concept.

I have to solve: calculate the fourier series of $$f(x)= x(\pi^2-x^2)$$
Then $ii)$ calculate the fourier series of f'in two ways
i)Develop to fourier series f'(derivative) ii)by differentiating each term of the fourier of f.

So far i writed it as $(x\pi^2-x^3)$ used the odd function property and from that i concluded there are not $a_0$ coefficient and $a_n$.

Is so far correct and what about the $ii)$.

Comment: You will not avoid the computation of coefficients $b_n$, you probably know how to calculate their integral expressions ?

Comment: Well i didn't said that i will avoid the computaiton of sin but the others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
 f(x) = x\left(\pi^{2} - x^{2} \right) \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad f'(x) = \pi^{2}-3x^{2}
$$

---

**A: Fourier series of derivative $\ f'(x) = \pi^{2}-3x^{2}$**

The derivative has *even* parity and will be a sum of cosines.

The Fourier amplitudes are computed via
$$
\begin{align}
  a_{0} &= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi }^{\pi } f'(x)  dx \\
%
  a_{k} &= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi }^{\pi } f'(x) \cos (k x) dx \\
%
  b_{k} &= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi }^{\pi } f'(x) \sin (k x) dx
\end{align}
$$
There are two basic integrals:
$$
\begin{align}
%
\int_{-\pi }^{\pi } \cos (k x) dx &=  
 0 \\
%
\int_{-\pi }^{\pi } x^{2} \cos (k x) dx &=  
 \left( -1 \right)^{k+1}\frac{4\pi}{k^{2}} \\
%
\end{align}
$$
The Fourier amplitudes for the derivative are
$$
\begin{align}
%
  a_{0} &=  0 \\
%
  a_{k} &=  \left( -1 \right)^{k+1} \frac{12}{k^{2}} \\
%
  b_{k} &=  0 \\
%
\end{align}
$$
The approximation of the derivative is
$$
 f'(x) = \pi^{2}-3x^{2} =
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 
a_{k}  \cos (kx)
= \color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 
\left( -1 \right)^{k+1} \frac{12}{k^{2}}  \cos (kx)}
$$
The plot sequence below provides a quality check on the computation. The parameter $m$ represents the highest value of $k$.

[image: approximation]

**B: Derivative of Fourier series for $\ f(x) = x\left(\pi^{2} - x^{2} \right)$**

The derivative has *odd* parity and will be a sum of sines.

Construct the Fourier series using these building blocks:
$$
\begin{align}
%
\int_{-\pi }^{\pi } x \sin (k x) \, dx &=  \left( -1 \right)^{k+1} \frac{2\pi}{k}\\ 
%
\int_{-\pi }^{\pi } x^{3} \sin (k x) dx &=  
\left( -1 \right)^{k+1} \frac{2\pi \left(k^{2}\pi^{2} - 6 \right)}{k^{3}}
%
\end{align}
$$
The Fourier amplitudes are 
$$
\begin{align}
%
  a_{0} &=  0 \\
%
  a_{k} &=  0 \\
%
  b_{k} &=  (-1)^{k+1}\frac{12 }{k^3} \\
%
\end{align}
$$
The approximation of the function is
$$
 f(x) = x\left(\pi^{2} - x^{2} \right) 
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 
b_{k}  \sin (kx) 
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 
\left( -1 \right)^{k+1} \frac{12}{k^{3}}  \sin (kx)
$$
The derivative of the Fourier series is
$$
 f'(x) 
= \frac{d}{dx} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 
b_{k}  \sin (kx) \right)
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 
\frac{d}{dx} \left( b_{k}  \sin (kx) \right)
= \color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 
\left( -1 \right)^{k+1} \frac{12}{k^{2}}  \cos (kx)}
$$
which matches the series for the derivative term-by-term.